# How could I speed up my pandas datetime slicing?

Tags: python, pandas, date, optimization

I have vast amounts of second by second sensor data, billions of rows that span days and potentially weeks. I also have a list of tens of thousands of start and end times for an event, also to the second. I am trying to identify the rows of sensor data which lie within each start and end time and mark the row as true in the event column but it is very slow. The events cannot overlap.

My attempt is as follows:

```
sensor_data = pd.DataFrame( columns = ["Event"], index = 
pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=15, freq="s"))

event_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {"Start":["2018-01-01 00:00:01","2018-01-01 00:00:08"], 
"End":["2018-01-01 00:00:03","2018-01-01 00:00:12"]})

sensor_data["Event"] = 0
    
event_data["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(event_data["Start"],utc=True)
event_data["End"] = pd.to_datetime(event_data["End"],utc=True)

for i in range(event_data.shape[0]):

    start = event_data["Start"].iloc[i]
    end = event_data["End"].iloc[i]    

    event_indexes = sensor_data.loc[start:end].index
    sensor_data.loc[event_indexes,"Event"] = 1
```

Comment: Can the events overlap?

Comment: Please post some sample data from the df

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a 200x speedup by changing the time format to seconds since epoch and then building ranges of integers to index for time instead of comparing times. Code I used below for ref.

```
event_data["Start"] = pd.to_datetime(event_data["Start"],utc=True)//1e9   
event_data["End"] = pd.to_datetime(event_data["End"],utc=True)//1e9   
ranges = []
for row_index, row in event_data.iterrows():
  ranges.append(np.arange(event_data["VisitStart"].iloc[row_index],event_data["VisitEnd"].iloc[row_index]))

sensor_data.loc[ranges,"event"] = 1
```